# How can I declare and reference an ECR repository in Terraform without jeopardizing its contents?

Tags: docker, terraform, aws-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ecr

I am building a Terraform configuration to deploy some containers to AWS ECS. Obviously, I must push the Docker images to ECR. I created a repository in ECR and pushed the images.

Now I'm automating. If I declare the `aws_ecr_repository` like so:

```
data "aws_ecr_repository" "service" {
  name = "myrepository"
}
```

then Terraform will manage it. I can eventually reference it with something like

```
image = "${aws_ecr_repository.myrepository.repository_url}"
```

in the process of building the ECS task definition.

I am under the impression that Terraform will delete this repository – or fail when it has images – when I run `terraform destroy` as a part of my development cycle. This would be bad, because then `terraform destroy` would either never complete or I would have to clear out the ECR repository for that command to complete successfully.

How can I best reference an ECR repository that already exists but I seemingly don't want Terraform to manage because Terraform may destroy data that lives outside of Terraform, i.e. the Docker images uploaded by release CI jobs?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want Terraform to manage it use the [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ecr_repository.html). This lets you get the data like this:

```
data "aws_ecr_repository" "example" {
  name = "example"
}
```

Then reference the url like:

```
${data.aws_ecr_repository.example.repository_url}
```

Comment: Your snippet is virtually the same as mine, in which Terraform was managing it. I did `terraform destroy` at some point and it destroyed the ECR repos.

Comment: If you are using the `data`  source and not the `resource` its not managed. Verify you dont have a `resource "aws_ecr_repository"` defined anywhere. Your second code block indicates you are referencing a resource and not a data source even though your first code block says its a data source. Check for the other one in your code.

Comment: I must have had it as a resource at some point. It seems to be working fine now.

Comment: One note for anyone reading these: If you previously had a "resource" and you switched it to "data" and did terraform apply it will delete the resource the first time you run terraform apply (because it's a change to the config). After that the "data" will be respected and it will not be created or deleted.

Comment: @josh803316 you can remove it from the state file and it wont destroy anything. Just use the [state removal command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html)

Comment: Thanks Brandon!